# How to load Powershell output into a SQL Table using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I'm trying to get all users that had been disabled in my domain and put it into a SQL Table. I'm trying to use SSIS to do that. Now that I can grab the right output and put it into a CSV file using this code:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | 
    Select Name | 
    Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\hou\Downloads\Test.csv
```

But since I'm going to run the package in different servers and I couldn't have a fixed location to store the file and load into SQL Table. So either I'm going to use a variable in the Execute Process Task (where I run the Powershell script) to store the CSV file, or use SSIS to store the output directly in SQL table.

But I don't know neither of those. How can I do that?

Comment: You can query LDAP directly from SSIS.  Have tried that instead of having to use powershell?

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125190/how-to-collect-ntfs-files-properties-and-insert-into-sql-server-table/125192?noredirect=1#comment230757_125192

Answer (score 0):

Location should be define in the script, i.e:

```
$Path = Get-Location
```

"$Path\Test.csv"

```
#Option 1 just a Name
$Path = Get-Location ; Get-ChildItem C:\temp | Select-Object Name | Export-CSV -Path "$Path\Test.csv"

## Option 2 Name, with other property
$Path = Get-Location ; Get-ChildItem C:\temp | Select-Object Name,mode | Export-CSV -Path "$Path\Test.csv"
```

For one liner script , use the "**;**" to separate the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading the data into SQL using PowerShell. There is a free PowerShell module from Microsoft called "sqlserver" that allows PowerShell to talk directly to SQL. You may already have it installed.

```
## Check if installed:
Get-InstalledModule -Name SqlServer
## If installed you can Update (you may need to run as local admin):
Update-Module -Name SqlServer
## If not installed (only need admin if you want all users to have access to this module):
Install-Module SqlServer
```

Once the module is installed there is a cmdlet called "Write-SqlTableData" to bulk copy data into SQL. The assumption is (1) the table already exists in SQL. (2) All the columns in the PowerShell Select match the order and datatype as they exist in the SQL table. In this case, there would be a SQL table with a single [Name] column. (3) You are using your AD credentials to access SQL, if not you will have to add credentials to the cmdlet.

The actual PowerShell code, update the variables in the quotes:

```
## Input Variables
$SqlServerName = ""
$SqlDatabaseName = ""
$SqlTableSchemaName = ""
$SqlTableName = ""

## Insert into SQL
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Select-Object Name | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $SqlServerName -DatabaseName $SqlDatabaseName -SchemaName $SqlTableSchemaName -TableName $SqlTableName -Force
```

As a side note, if you plan on doing a lot of PowerShell/SQL work, you may want to also install the "WFTools" module as it also has many additional SQL cmdlets.

Hope this helps.